# Unable to center the View in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

Please have a look at the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="202dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="100 de 554" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/word"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This gives the below UI

[image]

As you can see, I have used the methods to make the layout center.  But it is not centered properly, which means it is not in the middle of the screen.

Any idea to make it center?

Note: If I add manual padding and margins to make it center (vertically), it might look differently in different devices. That would be an issue.

Comment: I see it in the center. You mean center vertically?

Comment: @Perroloco: Yes. Vertically and Horizontally. To the middle of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="202dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="100 de 554" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/word"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically it wraps your content in a `LinearLayout` with `layout_centerInParent` set to `true`.

[android:layout_centerInParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerInParent)

Answer (score 2):

You can use RelativeLayout's centerVertical property, but I would do it like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="202dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="100 de 554" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/word"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyways, you should take a look at some android layout tutorials. If you use "alignParentTop" with RelativeLayout, it certainly wont be centered vertically ¬¬